# A continuous mapping between a quantity to RGB color?

Tags: python, colors

In my Python code I draw some points on a canvas. To each point there is an associated quantity f(P) where f is a function taking values between [0,f_{max}].

I would like to color the points such that the color corresponds to the value of f(P), and the mapping should be continuous.

The issue is colors in python are represented in RGB format in other words a function of 3 variables, so I am unsure how to approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map from [HSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html) (hue, saturation, value) to RGB, varying the hue according to your scalar value and setting saturation and value to constants.

```
import colorsys

def scalar_to_rgb(scalar):
    return colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(scalar, 1, 1)
```

Scale the value to between 0 and 1 before passing it to the function. The colours wrap around, 1 will give the same result as 0. If this is an issue you could use only part of the range between 0 and 1.